# Query Spring Integration For Most Recent Message processed

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to query a Spring Integration channel for the last time it received a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the classes [QueueChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/QueueChannel.html) and [AbstractPollableChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/AbstractPollableChannel.html), no there isn't.

The only option you have is to rely on message header `timestamp`, which is included into each message as its creation time. So if the message was created just before hitting the `QueueChannel` (e.g. by passive components like Transformer, Enricher or Gateway) it gives you pretty close time it arrived to your `QueueChannel`.

Comment: Sounds good. I guess I can then set that timestamp into a transient singleton and everything will be aware.